# Маршрутизация в Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Здравствуте! Я рубинист и начал осваивать Sails.js. Возникла проблема с указанием маршрутов страниц в роутере. Как ни пытался, всплывают ошибки.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне правильно указать страницы в роутере, например: `about`, `contact`, `help**` и т.п.
К примеру, я создал страницу "about.ejs", затем сгенерировал контроллер "PagesController.js для этой страницы, теперь нужно указать маршрут этой страницы в "routes.js". Пока в маршрутизаторе указана дефолтная домашняя страница '/': { view: 'homepage' }  . А как мне прописать маршрут до страницы "about.ejs"? Я делаю так: '/about' { view: 'about' } , типа как в Ruby on Rails, но ничего не выходит. Документация на английском, хоть я и разбираюсь в английском, но может что-нибудь не так понял. Вот в этом routes.js у меня возникла проблема.А так Sails мне очень понравился, очень хочется освоить! С уважением. Юрий.

Comment: Получилось!!! Все дело было в пропущенной запятой. Блоки кода нужно отделять запятой. Вот правильный вариант:  **                    '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
},
 '/about':  { 
 view: 'about'
} **

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.